# Adding http module to ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make http call from my ionic app to return some json data. But it shows the error:

> [$injector:nomod] Module '$http' is not available!

I think I have to add the module http to Angularjs. Please let me know how to add a new module like http to ionic framework. Thanks.

Comment: Show your code please ?

Comment: $http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });

Comment: angular.module('starter.controllers', [])


// A simple controller that fetches a list of data from a service
.controller('PetIndexCtrl', function($scope, PetService) {
  // "Pets" is a service returning mock data (services.js)
  $scope.pets = PetService.all();
})


// A simple controller that shows a tapped item's data
.controller('PetDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, PetService) {
  // "Pets" is a service returning mock data (services.js)
  $scope.pet = PetService.get($stateParams.petId);
});

Comment: Yes. @evc is right. See his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` is not module, it's a service, which is injected like this

```
angular.module('app').controller('TestController', function($scope, $http){
    //use $http here
    $http.get('https://stackoverflow.com').then(function(successResponse){
       $scope.data = successResponse;
    }, function(errorRepsonse){
       $scope.error = errorRepsonse;
    });
});
```

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)